# How to restrict bean instantiation in spring mvc (other than profile)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to restrict the bean instantiation. Currently, In the web application we are using the spring active profile for **client** specific bean instantiation. 
But now i want to restrict some of the bean instantiation specific to environment as well. How can i acheive both at the same time?
FYI, i have **env** build parameter which specify the environment as either dev, qa or prod.

Comment: Use profiles and define profiles for each environment.

Comment: I have already used the profile for client specific. In my build parameters i have specified the spring.active.profiles=client1. Now in addition to this i also want to use environment to restrict the bean instantiation for prod context.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [@Conditional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) as explained below

**Step 1**- Implement `Condition.matches` so as to specify when should the bean be created or not.

```
public class SomeCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        String env = System.getProperty("env");
        return env !=null ? "dev".equals(env); // modify it as per requirement
    }
}
```

**Step 2** - In the configuration class specify the above class as condition to decide the bean creation

```
@Configuration
public class SomeAppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Condition(SomeCondition.class)
    public MyBean myBean() {
      return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

**P.S.**: I assumed that you used Java config and `env` as system property.

Comment: Hi Bond, thanks for your reply. Currently, I'm not using the java config. I'm using the spring 3.2 version.

Comment: `@Conditional` is available from Spring 4.0 onwards. So you need to upgrade to use it. Also have a look at [this](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/conditionally-defining-spring-beans.html) blog post which explains conditional bean creation via xml. (*do note it involves some custom implementation*)